# Use more than one collect_list in one query in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe `data`:

```
root
 |-- userId: string 
 |-- product: string 
 |-- rating: double
```

and the following query:

```
val result = sqlContext.sql("select userId, collect_list(product), collect_list(rating) from data group by userId")
```

My question is that, does `product` and `rating` in the aggregated arrays match each other? That is, whether the `product` and the `rating` from the same row have the same index in the aggregated arrays.

Update:
Starting from Spark 2.0.0, one can do `collect_list` on struct type so we can do one `collect_list` on a combined column. But for pre 2.0.0 version, one can only use `collect_list` on primitive type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe there is no explicit guarantee that all arrays will have the same order. Spark SQL uses multiple optimizations and under certain conditions there is no guarantee that all aggregations are scheduled at the same time (one example is aggregation with `DISTINCT`). Since exchange (shuffle) results in nondeterministic order it is theoretically possible that order will differ.

So while it should work in practice it could be risky and introduce some hard to detect bugs.

If you Spark 2.0.0 or later you can aggregate non-atomic columns with `collect_list`:

```
SELECT userId, collect_list(struct(product, rating)) FROM data GROUP BY userId
```

If you use an earlier version you can try to use explicit partitions and order:

```
WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT * FROM data DISTRIBUTE BY userId SORT BY userId, product, rating
)
SELECT userId, collect_list(product), collect_list(rating)
FROM tmp
GROUP BY userId
```

Comment: How to use `cogroup` for large datasets like when I use `collect()` it throws out of memory exception `rdd1 = rdd2.cogroup(rdd3).collect`. Can you help on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]. can partitioning help I'm new to spark any help to resolve this.