# Is collect_list() guaranteed to keep relative ordering of rows?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Imagine that I have the following hive table:

```
+---+-----------+------------+
| id|featureName|featureValue|
+---+-----------+------------+
|id1|          a|           3|
|id1|          b|           4|
|id2|          a|           2|
|id2|          c|           5|
|id3|          d|           9|
+---+-----------+------------+
```

Now I run a query like the example below

```
SELECT 
  id,
  collect_list(idx),
  collect_list(val)
FROM
  ...
GROUP BY id
```

Am I GUARANTEED that "idx" and "val" will be aggregated and keep their relative order? i.e.

```
GOOD                   GOOD                   BAD                    
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    
| id|   idx|   val|    | id|   idx|   val|    | id|   idx|   val|    
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    
|id3|   [d]|   [9]|    |id3|   [d]|   [9]|    |id3|   [d]|   [9]|    
|id1|[a, b]|[3, 4]|    |id1|[b, a]|[4, 3]|    |id1|[a, b]|[4, 3]|    
|id2|[a, c]|[2, 5]|    |id2|[c, a]|[5, 2]|    |id2|[a, c]|[5, 2]|    
+---+------+------+    +---+------+------+    +---+------+------+
```

NOTE: e.g. It's BAD because for id1 [a, b] should have been associated with [3, 4] (and not [4, 3]). Same for id2

Comment: According to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408056/4522274), no. There is no guarantee, but there is a workaround, just use *struct* before collecting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to check if spark and hive would be different in this case. I ended up using struct for this task.