# What is the efficient way to sort Spark Dataset based on two column values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a large dataset of three columns in the following format:

```
col1   col2   col3
------------------
 a1     1      i1
 a1     1      i2
 a1     2      i3
 a3     2      i4
 a3     1      i5
 a2     3      i6
 a2     3      i7
 a2     1      i8
```

I wrote the following:

```
   val datase2 = dataset.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(collect_list("col3").as("col3"))
        .sort("col1", "col2")
        .groupBy("col1").agg(collect_list("col2"), collect_list("col3"))
        .toDF("col1", "col2", "col3").as[(String, Array[String], Array[String])]
```

To get the distinct values of `col2` from the resultant dataset I wrote the following:

```
dataset2.select("col3").distinct().show()
```

The above code works fine for small dataset but for large dataset I got the following type of result (just to illustrate the scenario of inconsistant resultant dataset):

```
col1     col2           col3
-----------------------------------
a1     [1, 2]      [[i1, i2], [i3]]
a2     [3, 1]      [[i6, i7], [i8]]
a3     [2, 1]      [[i4], [i5]]
```

As I did `sort("col1", "col2")` the output should be

```
col1     col2           col3
-----------------------------------
a1     [1, 2]      [[i1, i2], [i3]]
a2     [1, 3]      [[i8], [i6, i7]]
a3     [1, 2]      [[i5], [i4]]
```

`col2` will be in sorted order and the values of `col2` and `col3` would be consistent based on their array index. For example, the last row of above dataset would be

```
 col2           col3
-------------------------
[1, 2]      [[i5], [i4]]
```

but not

```
 col2           col3
-------------------------
[1, 2]      [[i4], [i5]]
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine records using `struct` and use `sort_array`:

```
dataset
  .groupBy($"col1")
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct($"col2", $"col3"))).alias("data"))
  .select($"col1", $"data.col2", $"data.col3")
```

Credits go to [user6910411)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408056/9613318).

Comment: Got an idea from your answer. Thanks.